# What wind forecast datasets are available for forcing a wave forecast model?

Tags: wind, weather-forecasting, wave-modeling, mediterranean

I am trying to set up a spectral wave model for waves forecasting in the Mediterranean. I need the meteorological forecast for this region. I am aware of the ECMWF datasets. But unfortunately, only the reanalyses datasets are freely available.

So, is there any free source for wind forecasting which covers the Mediterranean region?

Comment: That was fast XD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the GFS model is a global model. The data is released in the public domain, so you can use it for free for any lawful purpose. See complete terms of use [here](https://www.weather.gov/disclaimer). You can get the data [here](http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, on the website you are referring to I can only find data up to 20-03-2018 (i.e. today) while I need data for e.g. one week ahead. Is that possible?

Comment: @Rik That is when the model is initialized (started). Say you want the GFS at 0.25 degree resolution, then you'd go to when the most recent model was run, then choose the hour you would want. For example, if I wanted data 168 hours (1 week) out, then the link to the grib2 file is: http://nomads.ncep.noaa.gov/pub/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/gfs.2018032006/gfs.t06z.pgrb2.0p25.f168

Comment: @Rik Note how the link is set up. Particularly 2018032006 (year month day hour started), 06z (time initialized) and f168 (hour into future).

Comment: @Rik is it okay if I add another answer?

Comment: @BarocliniCplusplus It's clear now. I've downloaded the file and checked it. It seems that it only contains data for one specific time step, namely: 2018-03-27 06+0000. Is there one file that contains all the time step for next week for example. One more question: is there any user guide for GFS model that you recommend?

Comment: @ Eevee Yes, indeed it's O.K. this will enrich the discussion

Comment: @Rik Yes, the data file is only for one time step. If you go exploring the link that I posted in my original answer, you can find the other output. Concerning User Guide, the NWS provides the output. The model itself is very complex with (presumably) thousands of lines of FORTRAN code. There are model documentation available via the NWS http://www.emc.ncep.noaa.gov/GFS/doc.php

Comment: @Eevee always okay to add another answer if you believe it'll help solve the problem or add a useful alternative avenue, no need to ask the questioner or answerer.  Multiple answers is a sign of a quality StackExchange, as it collects more than one user's knowledge.  Or if you have a very slight adjustment, you could comment or be bold and edit it into the answer given.  But generally if it's more than just a slight input, give your own answer instead.